# react native componentWillUnmount - can use callback to stop component unmounting?

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to add code to callback function for `componentWillUnmount` that will stop callback from unmounting?  I want to provide message to user that says "are you sure you want to quit?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BackHandler module could solve your issue in android. For ios, you need to add  `gestureEnabled: false` in react navigation props and bind alert function with back button on header.